# An error has occurred Download interrupted on chrome extension while downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I published my chrome extension on chrome web-store but when I try to download it gives error "An error has occurred Download interrupted".Below is my manifest file

```
{
"background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
},
"browser_action": 
 {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Position Tracker"
 },
 "permissions": [ "browsingData", "management", "notifications","tabs", 
 "activeTab", "idle", "background", "webNavigation", "webRequest", 
 "webRequestBlocking", "proxy", "cookies", "storage", "contextMenus", 
  "unlimitedStorage", "\u003Call_urls>", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"  ],

 "description": "Easily Track Positions on Google Search Engine.",
  "icons": {
  "128": "icon.png",
  "16": "icon.png",
  "48": "icon.png"
 },
 "content_scripts": [
  {
    "css": [ "styles.css" ],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery-2.1.3.min.js", "content.js" ]
  }
 ],

"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Position Tracker",
 "version": "0.1",
 "author": "Amir Shah"
```

}

Comment: Did you Google it? I found: https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000138343-i-m-getting-a-download-interrupted-error-when-i-try-to-install-adblock-in-chrome

Comment: @Utkanos i tried it but no luck. I think the issue with the manifest file. I am asking for too many permissions